# Scheduled task to run .aspx page stuck on running

Tags: scheduled-tasks

Hey I have a scheduled task going which  basically laucnhes a .aspx page with IE Explorer, i know theres better ways of doing this i.e console apps etc but im stuck with this for the moment.

So the scheduled task runs fine and launches the ie and the page and the script on the onload on that page runs fine to. But the IE window stays open and the tasks remains as "Running". Preventing it from running the next time its due to run.

How can I get the scheduled tasks to stop "running" and maybe even close that IE windows cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to just make a HTTP request to the page, instead of opening a browser window, (get Firefox, okay?), you could launch `curl http://server/path/to/script.aspx` which is a command-line app, which makes the request and then quits immediately after.

For this, you'll need to download `curl` from http://curl.haxx.se/latest.cgi?curl=win32-ssl

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip but as stated for the moment im stuck with the scheduled tasks so im looking for solutions around that.

Comment: You can use `curl` easily with scheduled tasks. Just set `curl` as the program to use, instead of IE.

Comment: Cool I was wondering something just hit me. IN VB.NET can I close the IE Window from the code directly that would more than likely stop the task from running to

Comment: If it works, great. IE is a major security risk though. But you could go further and catch IIS and even Windows as being major security risks.